# execute a shell script from web page, output to web page

Tags: shell, web

I want to set up a web page on my home mac where an anonymous user could come to the page, enter a url and have the URL processed by a shell script (a one liner) and see the output on the webpage. I am running OS X 10.8.6 and want to use the built in Apache server if possible.

How would I:

call a shell script (or even a single command line command) from a web page and pipe the contents of a text field on that page to the script

have the web page update when the script completes and display all the output from the script?

Comment: are you using a programming language like C or PHP, or were you looking for having Apache call the shell script?

Comment: I'm looking for apache to call the bash shell script with the textfield contents as a command-line parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php for synchronous execution.  For asynchronous execution, you can use an ajax call to get the result of exec.

Note that it is not possible to make this safe.  Make sure only you can access the web page.

Comment: is there a way to do this directly without installing additional software such as php? For example, Apache has CGI - can that launch a shell script? If so how?

Comment: why is not possible to make it safe?  Can't they use [escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) and [escapeshellcmd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php)?